# Trying to use a tunnel from HE but some IPv6 connectivity is broken

Tags: networking, server, netplan, ipv6

I have a server from Kimsufi (OVH Eco branch) but unfortunatelly they only provide a /128 IPv6 block.

So, I decided to use a Hurricane Electric (HE) tunnel to have a /64 IPv6 block.

I've followed HE instructions in how to set up the tunnel, etc, but somehow some IPv6 connectivity is broken.

**Current main config - 50-cloud-init.yaml**

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
###
# default config - 50-cloud-init.yaml
###
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno0:
      set-name: eno0
      accept-ra: false
      dhcp4: true            
      dhcp6: false
      gateway6: 2001:470:1f20:a::2
      match:
        macaddress: 00:22:4d:84:93:df
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      addresses:
      # Routed /64: 2001:470:1f21:a::/64
        - 2001:470:1f21:a::1/64
        # James
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:ef54:7bad:b8b0:801d/64
        # LikeIcare
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:6e0c:b070:c4cc:619c/64
        # Lounge
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:35f1:20bb:67b2:efce/64
        # ApexBNC
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:9df3:0c29:2cca:036e/64
        # Relays
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:a239:ca6e:c932:c379/64
        # weechater
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:4384:4ba6:36be:d16d/64
        # Scheherazade
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:7cc5:506f:d124:345a/64
        # RiberHus
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:7966:7232:e0ca:8ccc/64
        # Vigilante
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:6171:fd09:929e:72e2/64
        # Gitnotifier
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:3b98:2cc0:dd51:2e16/64
        # BloodyMary
        - 2001:470:1f21:a:0612:5d3c:78d2:3b5e/64
```

**Current tunnel config - 99-he-tunnel.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    he-ipv6:
      mode: sit
      remote: 216.66.87.102
      local: 5.135.186.51
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: "2001:470:1f20:a::1"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      addresses:
        # Client IPv6 Address
        - 2001:470:1f20:a::2/64
```

**Warnings with current configurations**

```
** (generate:4594): WARNING **: 13:57:50.895: `gateway6` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
 
** (generate:4594): WARNING **: 13:57:50.897: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in he-ipv6 but also in eno0
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:53.256: `gateway6` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:53.259: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in he-ipv6 but also in eno0
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:53.311: `gateway6` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:53.314: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in he-ipv6 but also in eno0
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:54.629: `gateway6` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:54.630: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in he-ipv6 but also in eno0
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:54.631: `gateway6` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
 
** (process:4592): WARNING **: 13:57:54.631: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in he-ipv6 but also in eno0
```

When I try `curl -6 https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org` the connection just times out.

Using `mtr -6 nominatim.openstreetmap.org` on terminal only has the following as output:
[mtr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smlwx.png)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome, you configured the same IPv6 subnet on `eno0` and `he-ipv6`. This can not work. Step 1) remove ALL ipv6 configuration from `eno0` (`addresses`, `gateway6` and ipv6 DNS) activate the new config.
Test the tunnel it should work now. If so Step 2) ass the additional ipv6 to the `he-ipv6` interface.

Comment: I've tried it, but commands like `curl -6 https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org` still times out

Comment: best guess: problem with tunnel setup. can you `ping -6 2001:470:1f20:a::1`.  what is the output of  `ip route -6` ? what is the output of `traceroute -n -6 google.com` ? please add to your question

Comment: I've solved it by using only their IPv6 address. Too much time spent around this and I'm tired of trying to solve it. Thank you very much for trying to help, though. Cheers